# Open a Teams TaskModule from an Adaptive card

Tags: botframework, bots, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am trying to open a TaskModule from an adaptive Card.
 When I Use a HeroCard and embed an button  like this

```
Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
{
new TaskModuleAction("Start task", new { data = "open_task" }),
}
```

it results in a json like this:

```
  {
  "type": "invoke",
  "title": "Start task",
  "image": null,
  "text": null,
  "displayText": null,
  "value": "{\n  \"data\": \"open_task\",\n  \"type\": \"task/fetch\"\n}",
  "channelData": null
}
```

When clicking the Button my OnTeamsMessagingExtensionFetchTaskAsync function is called.

How would I accomplish the same when using adaptive Cards? None of the options Action.Submit, Action.OpenURL, Action.showCard seem to be the right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use adaptive card submit action type to open a task module.

> Below is the c# code snippet

```
new AdaptiveCard()
            {

                Actions =
                {
                    new AdaptiveSubmitAction()
                    {
                        Title = "Title",
                        Data = new TaskModuleDetail<string>() { Data = "data here" }
                    },

                }
            };
```

> TaskModuleDetail Class

```
public class TaskModuleDetail<T>
    {
        [JsonProperty("msteams")]
        public object Type { get; set; } = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"type\": \"task/fetch\" }");
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
```